# How to add copytoclipboard in blogger for a pastebin embedded

Tags: javascript, github, clipboard, pastebin

Im using Pastebin (and GitHub Gist sometimes) embedded on blogger and i want to add a copy to clipboard button , How can I do that ? 
is there a similar / alternative to pastebin that has an embedded code view and a copytoClipBoard option ?
because i don't want to write the html CopytoclipBoard code each time on a diffrent page/post ...etc

[image]